# Indentation goes wrong in python idle on Enter

Tags: python, python-idle

my idle indentation goes to right side when i enter in the previous line as shown in screenshot (marked in yellow where indentation suggested by python). same problem seen with same code in python 3.x and 2.x. any help is appreciated.

**Note**: indentation error seen if i choose to go with python suggested indent.

Problem Disappears if i comment out code

> self.directory = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(**file**)

[image]

Comment: When IDLE's smart indent seems wrong, it usually is because you forgot something, like the missing ) above, and IDLE responds to what you actually typed, rather than what you meant to type.  Same with odd SyntaxErrors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to close your parentheses on the `os.path.abspath` call. IDLE thinks you meant to do that, and it's lining up the indentation with the opening parenthesis, which is a common way of formatting statements that span multiple lines.